# How to call a method after `computed` in Emberjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I require to call a  method after `computed` is done. Currently I am adding a `class` name which works fine but my method does not log the result.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    classNameBindings: ['isSelected:highlight'],//adding class as expected
    firstBalanceType : '',
    firstBalanceAmount : '',
    lastBalanceType : '',
    lastBalanceAmount : '',
    isSelected : Ember.computed('card', 'selectedCard', function(){
        return this.get('card') === this.get('selectedCard');
    }),

    creditCard : Ember.computed('card','selectedCard', function(){
        console.log("card is", this.get(selectedCard)); //nothing consoles.
    })
});
```

Thanks in advance.

The purpose of this method to supply the card to next page.

Answer (score 0):

A callback in a [computed property](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/object-model/computed-properties/) is called whenever some part of the code (directly or indirectly) calls a `this.get('nameOfComputedProperty')`.

After the call, the resulting value (whatever the callback returns) is cached and is only computed again (by calling the callback) if the value for any of the dependent properties changes.

For your particular example, the callback will be called whenever you call `this.get('creditCard')` within your component and if its the first call or `'card'` or `'selectedCard'` values have changed.

Don't forget that [HTMLBars](https://github.com/tildeio/htmlbars) (in the template) can call the property getters behind the scene. This means that if you have any bindings to `creditCard` in your template that can also trigger the callback (with the same caching rules)

If you want something to happen whenever some value changes, you should just trigger that functionality wherever you make the change, there's no need for a computed property.

For example, if you have actions that change `card` or `selectedCard`, you can do your reaction there:

```
actions: {
  setCard(card) {
    this.set('card', card);
    this.triggerSomething();
  }
  setSelectedCard(card) {
    this.set('selectedCard', card);
    this.triggerSomething();
  }
}
```

Another way would be to use an [observer](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/object-model/observers/) but due note that this is usually the last resort:

```
onChange : Ember.observer('card','selectedCard', function(){
  this.triggerSomething();
})
```

Comment: My exact requirement is after the card is selected, I would like to store in to my service to consume by next page. for that after the card selected how to send to my serivce?

Comment: If I replace with `isSelected : Ember.computed.equal('card', 'selectedCard')` - class name is not applies

Comment: @3gwebtrain my mistake, the second argument in [`Ember.computed.equal`](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/2.14/namespaces/Ember.computed/methods/equal?anchor=equal) is a constant, not a computed property. I removed that suggestion

Comment: As well I am trying like this: `isSelected : Ember.computed('card', 'selectedCard', function(){
  this.setCreditCard()
  return this.get('card') === this.get('selectedCard');
 }),` But getting error as `ReferenceError: setCreditCard is not defined`

Comment: That's because a function by the name of `setCreditCard` doesn't exist. Like I said, you don't need a computed property. How are you setting `card` and how are you setting `selectedCard`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151020/discussion-between-3gwebtrain-and-nem035).

Answer (score 0):

Neither `card` nor `selectedCard` are defined in the class. Also the computed property which is logging to the console should also return the value of the property.

A computed property is evaluated only if any dependency changed **and** if it is read somewhere like in a template:

```
a: 1,
b: 1,
sum: Ember.computed('a', 'b', function () {
    console.log('hello')
    return this.get('a') + this.get('b')
})
```

At first nothing will log, then if you `.get('sum')` it will log and return 2. Then if you get again nothing will log. Then you can `.set('a', 3)` but nothing will log (yes, you did not read the `sum`). Then if you get the sum it'll return 4 and log.